# iPython line continuation of command shell string literal

Tags: ipython

In iPython, when using the command shell command (the exclamation point operator), is there a way to do line continuation of long string literals?

E.g.

```
t = !echo "Hello"\
"World"
t
```

produces ['Hello'] as the value for t instead of the expected ['HelloWorld'].

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "cell magic" (which is basically a multi-line version of other magics like `!`).  If you enter `%%bash` at the command prompt, it will give you a new line with `...`, meaning that you should type your command.  Press enter again, and you get another `...`, until you just hit enter twice in a row, and it runs your commands.  For example, you can type just the following.

```
%%bash --out t
echo "Hello "\
"World"
```

(and hit enter twice at the end).  It works as expected.  In particular, note the `--out t`, which stores the standard output in the variable `t`.  If you evaluate that now, you get `'Hello World\n'`.  You can also get the standard error output with `--err`, as described nicely on [this page](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/github.com/ipython/ipython/raw/master/examples/notebooks/Script%20Magics.ipynb).

In the ipython notebook, you just put the whole thing in one cell and evaluate it all together.  (If you haven't tried the notebook, I **highly** recommend it.)